# Retrieving largest indices of the bounded element in a multidimensional array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, indexing, indices

I have an multidimensional Array:

```
val M = Array.ofDim[Int](V, N)
```

Goal is to find largest V dimension index for which there exists a bounded element 0 < w0 <= W and return both indices and element value.

Currently I have this code snippet which works, but wondering if there is a nicer, more efficient way to do this.

```
M.zipWithIndex.reverse.collectFirst({
  case (arr, ind) if arr.exists(a => a <= W && a > 0) => {
    arr.zipWithIndex.find(a => a._1 <= W && a._1 > 0) match {
      case Some((weight, ind2)) => (ind, ind2, weight)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really better off with an imperative or recursive solution here.  I'll write a recursive one:

```
def finder(arr: Array[Array[Int]], w: Int, i: Int = 0, j: Int = 0): Option[(Int,Int,Int)] = {
  val ri = arr.length-i-1
  if (i >= arr.length) None
  else if (arr(ri)(j) > 0 && arr(ri)(j) < w) Some(ri,j,arr(ri)(j))
  else if (j+1 < arr(i).length) finder(arr,w,i,j+1)
  else finder(arr,w,i+1)
}
```

Then `finder(M,W)` should do what you want.  Note that this is also efficient--no boxing aside from the return value.

---

Edit--if you care about performance, here are the runtimes of the existing solutions on a 100x100 array which has no solutions or one solution at 77% of the way to the end (i.e. runtime should be about 1/4):

```
Original without answer:     65 μs / iteration
Original with answer at 1/4: 18 μs / iteration
```

Result table compared to original method, relative time taken (lower is faster, compiled with -optimise but that hardly makes a difference):

```
                  No Answer    1/4 Answer
Original            1.00          1.00
Rex                 0.55          0.72
4e6                 1.95          7.00
missingfaktor       2.41          1.91
Luigi               4.93          3.92
```

So your original method was actually faster than all of the suggestions, save for the recursive one.

Comment: This is why we need fast `for` loops. :(

Comment: Weird that mine is so slow when there is no answer, as it's more or less identical to 4e6's

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - It surprised me too, but it did seem consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Meh, pretty similar to the others, but it stops when it finds its target

```
def find(M: Array[Array[Int]], W: Int): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  for {
    x <- M.indices.reverse
    y <- M(x).indices
    a = M(x)(y)
    if 0 < a && a <= W
  } return Some(x, y, a)
  None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rex said, imperative approach in this case looks simpler

```
scala> val m = Array.tabulate(v,n)(_ + _)
m: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3), Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Array(2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> for { 
     | i <- v-1 to 0 by -1
     | j <- n-1 to 0 by -1
     | if m(i)(j) > 0 && m(i)(j) < 2
     | } yield (i, j, m(i)(j))
res23: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int, Int)] = Vector((1,0,1), (0,1,1))

scala> res23.headOption
res24: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write an iterator.

```
scala> def itr[A](as: Array[Array[A]]) = new Iterator[(Int, Int, A)] {
     |   private var r = 0 
     |   private var c = -1
     |   def next = {
     |     if(c == as(r).length - 1) {
     |       c = 0
     |       r += 1
     |     } else {
     |       c += 1
     |     }
     |     (r, c, as(r)(c))
     |   }
     |   def hasNext = {
     |     !((r == as.length - 1) && (c == as(r).length - 1))
     |   }
     | }
itr: [A](as: Array[Array[A]])java.lang.Object with Iterator[(Int, Int, A)]

scala> val xs = Array.tabulate(5, 6)(_ + _)
xs: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Array(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

scala> itr(xs).find { case (_, _, x) => 5 < x && x <= 7 }
res19: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,5,6))
```